# Casting a Generic Class<T> in C# from an Interface?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic class based on an Interface

```
public class SomeClass<T>() : ISomeClass 
{...}
```

and in it, I have a public method, which is an implementation of the `ISomeClass` interface and returns a `SomeClass<T>` type.

```
public SomeClass<T> SomeMethod()
{...}
```

Then I declare a variable somewhere else, based on the interface

```
private ISomeClass _someVariable;
```

Now, if I instantiate the class...

```
_someVariable = new SomeClass<SomeType>();
```

... I can access my public method

```
var anotherVariable = _someVariable.SomeMethod();
```

However, it returns an `ISomeClass` type and not a `SomeClass<T>`type. Why? Is this because I declare _someVariable as ISomeClass? (I've tried casting it `as SomeType<T>` as well, but still get a type `ISomeClass`.) What am I missing? (*other than a whiskey and some sleep?*)

Comment: Because `ISomeClass.SomeMethod` has a return type of `ISomeClass`.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding the actual code here. Can you show the entire code block and not seemingly unrelated fragments.

Comment: Please read [ask] and create a [mcve] instead of telling a story from which we have to mentally rebuild the code. Show the entire interface and implementation. `SomeClass<T> SomeMethod()` cannot implement a method from `ISomeClass` (well it can, but not as shown), let alone _return_ `ISomeClass`. The return type must match the interface exactly.

Comment: `SomeMethod()` declared as a method which returns `ISomeClass` why do you expect that it should return `ISomeClass<T>`?

Comment: I guess in your interface your method is defined as `ISomeClass SomeMethod()` making any instance of `ISomeClass` calling that method return an instance of the interface. You´d have to cast your `someVariable` to `SomeClass<T>`before.

Comment: @HimBromBeere _"I guess in your interface your method is defined as `ISomeClass SomeMethod()`"_ - yes, that's my guess too, but then `SomeClass<T> SomeMethod()` cannot implement that interface as the OP claims.

Comment: @CodeCaster it could via explicit implementation

Comment: Then there should be some proof in the code @Default. Now it is just guessing.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I know. I'm just saying it's possible. OP isn't showing the declaration of the entire interface either, but the comments are making assumptions about that as well. Not sure how my assumption differs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `someVariable` is `ISomeClass` (which it is), then the relevant question is: what type does `ISomeClass.SomeMethod()` return, because *that* is the definition being used; I'm guessing it returns `ISomeClass`, which is why `anotherVariable` is typed as `ISomeClass`.

To use the `SomeClass<T>.SomeMethod()` signature that returns a `SomeClass<T>`, `_someVariable` would *need to be known* as a `SomeClass<T>`, not just an `ISomeClass`.

Note that your `SomeClass<T>.SomeMethod()` method *won't actually satisfy that interface*, so you *probably* also have an explicit interface implementation somewhere:

```
ISomeClass ISomeClass.SomeMethod() => SomeMethod();
```

(which highlights the same problem)

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. The return class for the method is `SomeClass<T>`, that's why I am flummoxed why I get an ISomeClass return? Anyway, some eager beaver deemed this OT, so leave it there.

Comment: @ToshiBoy as the notes say: the main reason for that is because it *doesn't include key information*. In particular, the full `ISomeClass` interface would help. An actual runnable example would be better